# Cassandra, strange behavior after changing replication_factor

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am facing a strange situation when changing the replication_factor of an existing keyspace.

Using a cluster of three nodes, each running Datastax Cassandra community edition 2.0.11.

I created a keyspace 'training':

```
create keyspace training with replication = {
'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
'replication_factor': 1
};
```

Then,

```
use training;
```

Then,

```
create table customers (...);
```

Inserted three records. Queried the table from another node, and got the three records back, as expected.

Then, changed the replication_factor:

```
alter keyspace training with replication = {
'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
'replication_factor': 3
};
```

Queried the table. It showed zero records! After a few seconds, it showed 2 records. Then again zero records. Inserted two records. Now it sometimes shows 2 (new) records, sometimes 4 (2 new, 2 old). Same behavior on all three machines.

I am absolutely stumped. Does anybody have a clue why this is behaving this way?

Only one weird possibility comes to my mind: out of three nodes in the cluster, two are running Ubuntu, 64-bit OS, and the third is running 32-bit Windows 7 OS. Does that matter / explain this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved. I realized that I had not run "nodetool repair". Once I ran that the mysterious disappearance / reapparance stopped.

Comment: +1 for providing a good example of why `nodetool repair` needs to be run after altering the RF.